# How to best connect an FM transmitting GPIO pin to an antenna?

Tags: antenna, software-defined-radio, antenna-construction, impedance

I'm trying to use a RaspberryPi3 as a FM transmitter, using [pifm](https://github.com/rm-hull/pifm) and/or [PiFmRds](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds) to send audio in 88-108 MHz band. The RPi can then use the GPIO-4 pin to transmit between `1-250 MHz`. However, nobody want to ruin their HW while still optimizing the output by using a proper antenna.

1. What is the best antenna design to use? (A wire, dipole or something else?)
2. How to best connect the antenna? (I.e. Do we need impedance matching?)

I would like to avoid any amplifiers or extra active hardware.

**EDIT-1:**

1. I'm of course fully aware of the legalities of TX on FM band.
2. [Apparently](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications) the RPi GPIO impedance is around 30-60 Ohms.
3. This is an antenna problem, because the question is equally valid for any transmitter.
4. The best options I have seen so far is [this](https://fmdxing.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/simple-diy-fm-antennas-build-an-fm-loop-for-about-20/) FM loop or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4RM9YNIsIM&feature=youtu.be) quad loop...

Comment: You'll probably get more relevant answers at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Hardly, since this is an antenna question.

Comment: How to protect the GPIO of a Raspberry Pi is not an antenna question.

Comment: You are best off asking this type of question in the pi stack because they are the ones who are more likely to know for instance the actual impedance of the pins you want to use. There is no "best" type of antenna, it is all dependent on what you intend to use the transmitter for how much power is involved and what type of receiver you intend to use. If you are in the USA you can't legally transmit on those frequencies without a license unless your transmission can not be heard beyond 200 ft. You are responsible for being in compliance of that. If you are not the fine is $10,000 per day.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you stay off frequencies above 108 megahertz to 250 megahertz. That falls squarely in the middle of aeronautical and navigation bands and those people really don't play around if you start affecting their stuff.

Comment: I don't agree. Just imagine the question without "RPi" being mentioned at all. Still same antenna and frequency. Also I specifically said no extram amps etc. which means that it's probably well within global legal range of a few mW.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/is-it-legal-to-broadcast-an-fm-radio-signal-with-a-raspberry-pi-zero/7278#7278

Comment: @not2qubit If you want the question without "RPi", then edit it so it doesn't say "RPi". People aren't going to imagine the question to be something other than what it is.

Comment: You might also want to explain why the antenna instructions in the pifm README don't answer your question.

Comment: To expand upon the question: As a required subset of "best connect": Is it possible to wire up an antenna so reactive that it would damage a CMOS level SoC digital output?  If so, what kinds of general antenna and feed configurations should be avoided to prevent this?

Comment: I've edited the title. A 20 cm wire antenna can't possibly be as efficient as, for example, the ones I've linked. However, if I choose to use such a big antenna, I'd be quite worried about some sort of back-feed or ESD that could zap the GPIO (as it was never meant to do this.) How could that be prevented?

Comment: @hotpaw2 You answered at the same time! Yes, that is the kind of question I'm looking for an answer to.

Comment: FYI, here are two articles that relate to transmitting with the Pi:  http://qrznow.com/transmitting-fm-am-ssb-sstv-and-fsq-with-just-a-raspberry-pi/  and  http://www.rtl-sdr.com/transmitting-fm-am-ssb-sstv-and-fsq-with-just-a-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research, I've decided to answer my own questions 
as I find the current answers insufficient. Evidently the "best" antenna also seem to be the simplest.

From the article: 
`"Antenna 101: Let’s Review the Basics"` *by Dan Farber* (**AC0LW**) in the 
magazine *The Spectrum Monitor* [July, 2016].

> Consider once again the humble dipole. In its most basic form, it is 
>   cut to resonance at a desired frequency in a single band, and fed with
>   coaxial cable. Notice that one side of the dipole is thus connected to
>   the coax’s shield. Down at the radio end, the coax shield is connected
>   to RF ground, that is to say the grounded side of the coax connector. 
>   This works fine with no additional RF grounding.

This and the well known fact that the impedance of a:

- `1/4-wave vertical` with good RF ground is **~35** Ohms.
- `1/2-wave dipole` is **~70** Ohms.

This matches very well with the **GPIO impedance** that is believed to be 
somewhere between **30-60 Ohms**. ([How to test?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127046/what-is-output-impedance-of-a-pin)) Thus we can expect a natural impedance matching, or at least close enough, which is probably why these simple wire antennas work so well.

So as noted by the commenters in [this](http://makezine.com/projects/raspberry-pirate-radio/) link, a simple 1/4-wave wire with 
a 1/4-wave ground along the table, will be quite efficient. The wires also 
has to be electrically isolated, to help prevent possible static damage.

**How to best prevent GPIO ESD damage?**

There are several ways applicable here:

1. Use a ESD/TSV chip such as the [TPD1E01B04](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tpd1e01b04) with Cio=0.2 pF.
2. Use a simple resistor with R >= 100 K Ohms.
3. <strike>Use an inductor or inductive coil with X >= 100K @ 100 MHz.</strike>

In each case you should connect the part between the antenna wire 
and device GND. Please see [THIS](http://hpfriedrichs.com/radioroom/bleeder/rr-bleeder.htm) excellent blog about how to prevent static and lightning damage.

> **WARNING** I now recommend against using an inductor only, as it would force ground the GPIO pin, if set to 1 at DC during any other time, before the HF has been activated. This would surely damage your RPi.

**A simple band-pass filter**

The construction of a passive Band Pass Filter can be seen [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuxNGWcftc8) and another filter is very nicely described [HERE](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_4.html). In the video he uses the following values, but can probably be tuned even more.

```
Cgnd = 10 pF
Cio  = 2.2 pF
Rgnd = 1 K
```

[image: passive Band Pass Filter]

(Same as in video, if R1 is removed.)

**To amplify the GPIO signals**

Please look at [THESE](http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits) RPi GPIO driver aspects.

**NOTE-1:** For those concerned about the transmitted power, I've estimated it to be about `0.37 mW` in [THIS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/63624/17798) answer.

**EDIT-1:** I've found a few more excellent resources that explains exactly how this should be done.

The first one is: [QRPi - A Raspberry Pi QRP TX Shield Design](https://www.tapr.org/pdf/DCC2015-QRPi-HA7DCD.pdf), from where:

> However there were still one thing missing: no buffer stage to protect
>   the BCM2835 SoC's clock generator output stage. Hardware failure due
>   to the unbuffered operation of the WsprryPi program was reported by a
>   few HAM operators, possibly due to overload from nearly broadcast
>   transmitter stations. If buffer amplifier was already needed it was a
>   good idea to add some gain to the system. Eventually using a single
>   FET amplifier stage [fig 7] 10 dB gain achieved, delivering +20 dBm
>   output power at the end of the LPF [fig 4]...
>   For ESD and static discharge protection an ESD suppressor diode was 
>   added to the antenna terminal of the circuit.

The other ones are:

- [20M WSPR-Pi (QRPi) software installation guide for different HAM TX modes](http://j.mp/tapr-qrpi)
- [Raspberry Pi QRP TX Shield for WSPR on 20 Meters](https://www.tapr.org/kits_20M-wspr-pi.html)
- [Weak Signal Propagation Reporter Network](http://wsprnet.org/drupal/)
- [WSPR transmitter using NTP based frequency calibration](https://github.com/JamesP6000/WsprryPi)

There are several great links to filter, amplifier and buffer designs there. In addition, a simple design can allow you to transmit in the 20m HAM band several thousands of kilometers. Amazing.

The GitHub README from the last link, basically concludes all my original questions:

> As the Raspberry Pi does not attenuate ripple and noise components
>   from the   5V USB power supply, it is RECOMMENDED to use a regulated
>   supply that has   sufficient ripple supression. Supply ripple might be
>   seen as mixing products   products centered around the transmit
>   carrier typically at 100/120Hz.
>
> DO NOT expose GPIO4 to voltages or currents that are above the
>   specified   Absolute Maximum limits. GPIO4 outputs a digital clock in
>   3V3 logic, with a   maximum current of 16mA. As there is no current
>   protection available and a DC   component of 1.6V, DO NOT
>   short-circuit or place a resistive (dummy) load   straight on the
>   GPIO4 pin, as it may draw too much current. Instead, use a
>   decoupling capacitor to remove DC component when connecting the output
>   dummy   loads, transformers, antennas, etc. DO NOT expose GPIO4 to
>   electro- static   voltages or voltages exceeding the 0 to 3.3V logic
>   range; connecting an   antenna directly to GPIO4 may damage your RPi
>   due to transient voltages such   as lightning or static buildup as
>   well as RF from other transmitters   operating into nearby antennas.
>   Therefore it is RECOMMENDED to add some form   of isolation, e.g. by
>   using a RF transformer, a simple buffer/driver/PA   stage, two
>   schottky small signal diodes back to back.

Answer (score 3):

To be legal, you will need a low-pass or FM band-pass filter between the Pi's digital output and any antenna.  Otherwise, the antenna will also be transmitting at a bunch of harmonic frequencies well outside your intended band (into multiple higher frequency bands at 2X, 3X, 4X, 5X, etc. your intended FM frequency.)

Added: This is because periodic digital waveforms (produced by digital IO pins) contain lots of energy at lots of harmonic frequencies (Fourier's theorem).

Also, see this question: [Super-low-tech VHF low-pass filter construction?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7279/super-low-tech-vhf-low-pass-filter-construction)

Added #2: Given that the current output of a Pi's 3.3V GPIO pin is recommended to be kept below somewhere between 3 mA to 16 mA (depending on how many other GPIO outputs are being used), an impedance (resistor or ?) of somewhere in the range of 220 Ohms to 1.5k Ohms might be required somewhere in the matching network between the output and a 50 Ohm antenna load.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about matching to a suitable antenna. (Which could even incorporate a filter!)

Comment: I interpret "best" to include "legal".  And, yes, a proper (legal) filter could also include a proper match.

Comment: Yes, but you don't at all answer the aspects of matching and antenna design which were actually asked about. This answer is incomplete.